# statsmodels.formula.api Importerror ('cannot import name 'TimeSeries''.)

Tags: python, statsmodels

While in Python importing statsmodels.formula.api i get an ImportError: 'cannot import name 'TimeSeries''. I ve read about the analogic problems other users have but didnt get the relevant answer from there. I have the statsmodels version 0.6.1 and statsmodels.formula works well. How do you think where the problem is? Thank you in advance. Appreciate any help :)

I m using Anaconda 4.3.1, Python 3.6.0, Statsmodels 0.6.1

**traceback im getting while importing is :**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
C:\Users\e.elis\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\statsmodels\formula\api.py in <module>()
----> 1 from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import GLS
  2 gls = GLS.from_formula
  3 from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import WLS
  4 wls = WLS.from_formula
  5 from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

C:\Users\e.elis\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\__init__.py in <module>()
  ----> 1 from .linear_model import yule_walker
  2 
  3 from statsmodels import NoseWrapper as Tester
  4 test = Tester().test

  C:\Users\e.elis\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in <module>()
  50                                           cache_readonly,
  51                                           cache_writable)
  ---> 52 import statsmodels.base.model as base
  53 import statsmodels.base.wrapper as wrap
  54 from statsmodels.emplike.elregress import _ELRegOpts

  C:\Users\e.elis\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in <module>()
  3 import numpy as np
  4 from scipy import stats
  ----> 5 from statsmodels.base.data import handle_data
  6 from statsmodels.tools.tools import recipr, nan_dot
  7 from statsmodels.stats.contrast import ContrastResults

  C:\Users\e.elis\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in <module>()
  6 from statsmodels.compat.numpy import np_matrix_rank
  7 import numpy as np
  ----> 8 from pandas import DataFrame, Series, TimeSeries, isnull
  9 from statsmodels.tools.decorators import (resettable_cache, cache_readonly,
  10                                           cache_writable)

  ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeSeries'
```

Comment: I think my last comment wasn't relevant. Please edit your question to include the full traceback

Comment: You could verify by importing statsmodels.formula.api as smf and using dir(smf) than it doesn't contain TimeSeries

Comment: Also, what version of `statsmodels` are you using? I cannot find that line of code in [`statsmodels.formula.api`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/formula/api.py) which made me think you were doing that import yourself. Without the full traceback it's not clear where the error comes from.

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you. I am a new user here and can miss some needed notes while questioning. I have edited my question and hope that now it contains enought info on the Error.

Answer (score 1):

what's your pandas's version, pandas 0.20+ requires statsmodels 0.8 or newer.
Reference: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3752